# Error en un archivo js: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El dia de hoy trate de usar unas funciones de jquery offline, descargue los archivos que considere que serian necesarios para su funcionamiento pero no resulto nada.

```
(function($){
$("#frm_login").submit(function(ev){
    $("#alert").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php/Login/Validation',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(json);
            window.location.replace(json.url);
        },
        statusCode:{
            400: function (xhr) {
                $("#username > input").removeClass('is-invalid');
                $("#password > input").removeClass('is-invalid');
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (json.username.length != 0) {
                    $("#username > div").html(json.username);
                    $("#username > input").addClass('is-invalid');
                }
                if (json.password.length != 0) {
                    $("#password > div").html(json.password);
                    $("#password > input").addClass('is-invalid');
                    
                }
            },
            401: function (xhr) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //console.log(json);
                $("#alert").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ json.msg +'</div>');
            }
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
}); })(jQuery)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las librerías que cargue

Y estos son los errores que me salen al momento de trabajar offline

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no creo que sea la forma de hacerlo, pues asi solo tienes la funcionalidades, pero no tienes como hacer un llamado de la forma `$.`

Comment: Y como me lo recomendarias, si uso los enlaces directos, no me sucede el error.

Comment: No puedo decir nada pues no he trabajado con jQuery de forma offline

Comment: Para evitar el error que se te presenta en la consola debes descargar el archivo de **jQuery** a tu proyecto y luego apuntar al archivo descargado, es decir: `<script src="ruta/jquery.js"></script>` Eso es, si vas a trabajar **offline**

Comment: ¿Has probado de importar el código del jQuery antes que los otros JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de utilizar el objeto JQuery es:

```
$(function() {
 tu código;
});
```

Y tú lo tienes así:

```
($(function() {
 tu código;
});
```

Ese paréntesis ( antes del $ está de mas

Comment: Ya no seria necesario el `(jQuery)` al final del codigo